# How to use rank operator instead of each in APL

Tags: mapping, apl, dyalog

I have

```
dummytxt←'abcdefghijk'
texttoadd←'down'
rfikv←20 30 50
```

and need following output

```
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

I can do it with:

```
scenv←(¯10↑¨(⊂dummytxt),¨⍕¨rfikv),¨⊂texttoadd
```

but please help me to write without each operator but using rank `⍤`

I use Dyalog APL, but please do not use trains.

Thank you

Comment: `↓(dummytxt{¯10↑⍺,⍕⍵}⍤1 0⊢rfikv),⍤1⊢texttoadd` ?

Comment: Rank is used for orthotopic (rectangular in the N dimension sense) data. If your data is ragged (uneven lengths), and therefore not orthotopic/rectangular, as yours is. you want each, as you have it. Right tool for the right job and all that.

Comment: @DanBron OP seeks to increase her understanding of Rank by translating a very Each'y expression. Btw, the data *is* rectangular since it only consists of simple scalars and vectors, which obviously cannot be ragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions using *Each*, like `f¨x`, can be expressed in terms of *Rank* as `{⊂f⊃⍵}⍤0⊢x` (note that `⊢` is to separate the array right operand, `0` from the array right argument `x`). In other words, on the scalars of the argument we:

1. disclose the scalar: `⊃⍵`
2. apply the function: `f⊃⍵`
3. enclose the result: `⊂f⊃⍵`

A similar expression applies for the dyadic case, `x f¨y`, but we need to:

1. disclose both scalars: `(⊃⍺)`…`(⊃⍵)`
2. apply the function: `(⊃⍺)f(⊃⍵)`
3. enclose the result: `⊂(⊃⍺)f(⊃⍵)`

This gives us `x{⊂(⊃⍺)f(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢y`. We can thus use *Rank* to build our own *Each* operator which allows both monadic and dyadic application of the derived function:

```apl
      Each←{⍺←⊢ ⋄ ⍺ ⍺⍺{×⎕NC'⍺':⊂(⊃⍺)⍺⍺(⊃⍵) ⋄ ⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵}⍤0⊢⍵}
      (¯10↑Each(⊂dummytxt),Each⍕Each rfikv),Each⊂texttoadd
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

Alternatively, we can substitute the two simpler equivalences into your expression:

```apl
      (¯10{⊂(⊃⍺)↑(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢(⊂dummytxt){⊂(⊃⍺),(⊃⍵)}⍤0{⊂⍕⊃⍵}⍤0⊢rfikv){⊂(⊃⍺),(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊂texttoadd
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

Notice that we are enclosing `texttoadd` so it becomes scalar, and then we use `⍤0` to address that entire scalar, only to disclose it again. Instead, we can use `⍤0 1` to say that want to use the entire *vector* right argument when applying the function, which in turn doesn't need to disclose its right argument:

```apl
      (¯10{⊂(⊃⍺)↑(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢(⊂dummytxt){⊂(⊃⍺),(⊃⍵)}⍤0{⊂⍕⊃⍵}⍤0⊢rfikv){⊂(⊃⍺),⍵}⍤0 1⊢texttoadd
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

`rfikv` and `¯10` are a simple scalars, so disclosing them has no effect:

```apl
      (¯10{⊂⍺↑(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢(⊂dummytxt){⊂(⊃⍺),(⊃⍵)}⍤0{⊂⍕⍵}⍤0⊢rfikv){⊂(⊃⍺),⍵}⍤0 1⊢texttoadd
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

`dummytxt` is in the same situation as `texttoadd` above, but as left argument, so we can skip the enclose-disclose and ask Rank to use the entire vector left argument; `⍤1 0`:

```apl
      (¯10{⊂⍺↑(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢dummytxt{⊂⍺,(⊃⍵)}⍤1 0{⊂⍕⍵}⍤0⊢rfikv){⊂(⊃⍺),⍵}⍤0 1⊢texttoadd
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

This is about as simple as it gets using a general method. However, if we instead observe that the only non-scalar is `rfikv`, we can treat `dummytxt` and `texttoadd` as global constants and express the entire thing as a single `⍤0` function application on `rfikv`:

```apl
      {⊂(¯10↑dummytxt,⍕⍵),texttoadd}⍤0⊢rfikv
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

Of course, *Each* can do this too:

```apl
      {(¯10↑dummytxt,⍕⍵),texttoadd}¨rfikv
 defghijk20down  defghijk30down  defghijk50down
```

Comment: Adám, thank you for very detailed answer (and all you guys)
1. In last answers, you forgot about ``¯10``, that is why I assume final answer is
``{⊂(¯10↑dummytxt,(⍕⍵)),texttoadd}⍤0⊢rfikv``

Comment: @YuliiaSerhiienko You're welcome. Thanks for pointing that out — fixed. And sorry for messing up your post.

Comment: Could you please explain what means ``⍺⍺`` here  ``Each←{⍺←⊢ ⋄ ⍺ ⍺⍺{×⎕NC'⍺':⊂(⊃⍺)⍺⍺(⊃⍵) ⋄ ⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵}⍤0⊢⍵}``

Comment: @YuliiaSerhiienko To avoid clutter, maybe ask a separate question: *I saw the following code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252281/5306507) answer: `Each←{⍺←⊢ ⋄ ⍺ ⍺⍺{×⎕NC'⍺':⊂(⊃⍺)⍺⍺(⊃⍵) ⋄ ⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵}⍤0⊢⍵}`…*

Comment: Adám, thank you, created separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299517/how-to-build-own-each-operator-using-rank-operator-in-dyalog-apl)