# How to build own Each operator using Rank operator in Dyalog APL

Tags: apl, dyalog

I saw answer in this question [How to use rank operator instead of each in APL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247544/how-to-use-rank-operator-instead-of-each-in-apl/58252281#58252281) how to build own Each operator using Rank `⍤`.

Monadic Each `f¨x` can be represented as `{⊂f⊃⍵}⍤0⊢x`

Dyadic Each `x f¨y` can be represented as `x{⊂(⊃⍺)f(⊃⍵)}⍤0⊢y`

In terms of this please answer following questions:

1. Why Each `¨` operator can be represented as
   `Each←{⍺←⊢ ⋄ ⍺ ⍺⍺{×⎕NC'⍺':⊂(⊃⍺)⍺⍺(⊃⍵) ⋄ ⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵}⍤0⊢⍵}`
2. What means `⍺⍺` in the expression above

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This definition basically combines the monadic and dyadic cases which you listed above. `×⎕NC'⍺'` will return `1` if `⍺` exists and `0` otherwise, so it checks if you used `Each` monadically or dyadically.
2. `⍺⍺` is the left operand of the dop `Each`. It is the `f` in `x f Each y` or `f Each y`

Comment: Richard, 1. Is understandable, thank you. 2. Is still not clear. That is why cannot get all expression

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same combined operator in a more verbose form, with comments:

```
Each←{  ⍝ Monadic operator; ⍺⍺ is the operand function
    ⍺←⊢  ⍝ If called monadically ⍺ won't do anything (it will be the no-op function)
    Apply←{  ⍝ This operator applies its operand function (⍺⍺) to disclosed argument(s)
             ⍝ and encloses the result
        ×⎕NC'⍺': ⊂ (⊃⍺) ⍺⍺ (⊃⍵)  ⍝ if we have a left argument, apply ⍺⍺ dyadically (enclose both)
                 ⊂      ⍺⍺ (⊃⍵)  ⍝ otherwise, apply ⍺⍺ just on the enclosed ⍵
    }
    ⍝ Now we're ready to apply to separate elements:
    ⍺ ( (⍺⍺ Apply)⍤0 ) ⍵  ⍝ Even though we have ⍺ here, it may be ⊢ causes a monadic call to ⍺⍺
}
```